# Connect to friend in same network but different Ip?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I want to ping/file transfer to my friend whose ip address is 172.20.1.55 and mine is 172.20.64.69, we both r in same network of college but I am not able to connect.. college runs on cisco how can I do it.. I have a router if that can help..

Subnet: 255.255.248.0

Comment: Connect using what? Without telling what type of connection you're trying to do, its going to be impossible to help you. Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: Also, what is your subnet? Its also possible that their college network drops those requests as they wouldn't want amateur students probing for devices.

Comment: This is impossible for us to answer without 1) knowing the design of your college's network, 2) you having control over that design (which isn't going to happen)

Comment: @LPChip I am not able able to even ping him

Comment: @Tim 255.255.248.0

Comment: Your message was meant for @Tim but your problem is the subnet. With a subnet of 255.255.248.0 you can only find people in the range of 172.20.1.x to 172.20.7.x. You need at least a subnet mask of 255.255.191.0 to be able to breach this big of a gap. Or change your ip address where the 3rd digit is between 0 and 7.

Comment: Just a suggestion that you and your friend can connect to a network that is not provided by the school. Because your campus network may have VLANs set up and there is no routing between different VLANs.

Comment: Open Google Drive drag and drop file.  Right click file, sharing and enter your friends gmail address.  Now he can access the file.   The same thing can be done for a folder,   Otherwise you will have to connect to a common VPN to do this.  Chances are that a firewall blocks direct connection.  You could contact IT, and see if there is an approved way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the subnet.

With a subnet of 255.255.248.0 you can only find people in the range of 172.20.1.x to 172.20.7.x.

You need at least a subnet mask of 255.255.191.0 to be able to breach this big of a gap. Or change your ip address where the 3rd digit is between 0 and 7.

Comment: Do I have to change my Setting from Dynamic to static and then use this custom subnet??

Comment: Yes, otherwise you cannot change your ip adress or subnetmask.

Comment: Can you explain why you're implying that computers in different subnets cannot connect to each other? (Routers literally exist to allow that. If it were impossible, the Internet wouldn't work.)

Comment: And what do you mean by "find people" here – are you talking about Windows "network browsing"? Neither ping nor file sharing requires anything of that sort, because OP already has the correct IP address.

Comment: @grawity that's how I learned it. Fee free to post an answer to correct me.